# Dynamcially fit height of tableview according to its cells content into the scrollview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to Fit A UIVIew and a Tableview in a ScrollView But The table view Height is not Dynamically increasing according to the avaualable cells.

What I have done is.

1. Gave TableView Height constant and priority to 999
2. Made an outlet of the table view height content and added this code

> ```
>  self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.myNewTableView.contentSize.height
>  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
> ```

3. Made tablview scrollable to false

But the TableView Height is not increasing according to cells

[Here](https://github.com/SwiftGuides/Dynamic-TableView-Height-Example-NOt-working-.git) is the Example code of My Code.

***TableviewCell:-***

```
import UIKit

class NewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

***ViewController:-***

```
import UIKit

class NewViewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myNewTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myNewTableView.rowHeight = 60
        myNewTableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    }

}

extension NewViewViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell
        cell.testLabel.text = "Testing the height of tableview"

        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.myNewTableView.contentSize.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        return cell
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  `self.tableViewHeightConstraint` is not connected to the storyboard `tableView`. I think you mistakenly deleted it in storyBoard. After connecting this constraint, it's working fine. Please check the following attachments.

[image]

**After this change Output:-**

[image]

Comment: So the tableview height priority should be 1000? instead of 999?

Comment: In your case, It will work for both values(999,1000). One thing you should keep in mind is it should not create conflicts.

Comment: 1000 is default value assign by storyboard, while creating the constraint

Comment: You don't have to change any code. Please make a connection to your constraint from storyBoard.

Comment: Thanx Man it's working, just the last rows cuts #19 row not showing properly if I just connect it wth height outlet

Comment: It's due to padding issue. self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.myNewTableView.contentSize.height + 20 . addd extra 20 point's to solve this issue.

Comment: I managed to solve this in storyboard Thanx man you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it here

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.myNewTableView.contentSize.height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Already Tried this But i think there is some issue on adding A View on ScrollView i am also trying and checking if my constraints are ok to achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will help you.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.YOUR_TABLEVIEW.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.YOUR_TABLEVIEW_HEIGHTCONSTRAINT.constant = self.YOUR_TABLEVIEW.contentSize.height
}
```